# error tracking for server on flask

Tags: python, flask, error-handling

I have a server written on flask and I need to do error tracking (name of error, what caused the error, name of file and line with error).
How should I do it?
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enable the flask debugger, by setting debug to True for your flask app.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

As you shouldn't enable debug for a production server, you can create a logging
handler as follows: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/errorhandling/

Comment: and what will it do? could you, please, describe more precisely?

Comment: you will get a traceback for debbuging, as explained in werkzeug documentation: http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/debug/